# Display GPU monitoring while training in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, gpu

I'm writing a Jupyter notebook for a deep learning training, and I would like to display the GPU memory usage while the network is training (the output of `watch nvidia-smi` for example).

I tried doing a cell with the training run, and a cell with `nvidia-smi`, but obviously the latter is run only once the first is done, which is pretty useless. Is it possible to run these cells in parallel ?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Not sure if this will work but try this package: https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Comment: Is there any reason you really need to display the information in the notebook? You could use a tool like https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop or https://github.com/isrish/GPUWebDashboard if you prefer a web based version. The solution from the previous comment is a bit too overkill for this little problem in my opinion.

Comment: You can also do something like `vtop` or (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38560/gpu-usage-monitoring-cuda) in your terminal to monitor the GPU usage.

Comment: @critop not really, I just thought it would be more convenient to see it all in the same place, the notebook. I could still ask the user to ssh on the machine and launch the commands by himself, but the interest of the notebook is therefore limited in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

you can use "GPU Dashboards in Jupyter Lab"

[GPU Dashboards in Jupyter Lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9mRk.png)

Introduction
NVDashboard is an open-source package for the real-time visualization of NVIDIA GPU metrics in interactive Jupyter Lab environments. NVDashboard is a great way for all GPU users to monitor system resources. However, it is especially valuable for users of RAPIDS, NVIDIA’s open-source suite of GPU-accelerated data-science software libraries.[ref](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-dashboards-in-jupyter-lab/)

Answer (score 1):

This might help!
NVIDIA just launched the interactive GPU monitoring specifically for **jupyter lab**

Check this out here: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-dashboards-in-jupyter-lab/

Some Images:

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

Looks promising, isn't it?